# Is it better to create multiple layout files for one activity or change a layout programmatically?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, layout

I'm currently creating a Quiz section for an app. This is what it looks like for the most part:

[image]

My problem is that the number of answers for each question can vary from 2-4. I can see two solutions for this:

1. Create multiple layouts with the correct number of answers. When the user moves to the next question, I change the layout according to how many answers there are for that question.
2. Have one layout for the activity. Determine how many answers there are for a question and alter the layout programmatically.

Which of the two is the better route, or is there an even better alternative?

Comment: Better how? Both have advantages and disadvantages.

Answer (score 3):

The best solution for your problem is to use a `ListView` or a `RecyclerView` because these components are dynamic and can display from 0 to n views perfectly.

`ListView`: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html

`RecyclerView`: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/recyclerview/package-summary.html

After use it, you are able to control when your user click.

Answer (score 0):

Use a recyclerview [Creating android recyclerview](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html)

Answer (score 0):

Definitely the 2nd approach is better,

Why? Because in 1st approach you will be inflating the entire layout for each question. With 2nd approach you can just change the content of [TextView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html) and the adapter of [RecylerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) that publishes your answer.